# Migrate Java Project From Netbeans 7.1.2 to a newer Netbeans version

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, migration

I want to now if there is a mechanism or an automated way to migrate a generated GUI (that was used with Java 6) in Netbeans 7.1.2 to a newer version of Netbeans (that of course is using Java 7)?

The export settings from the old one and import it to new one is not actually very helpful, also, when i solve all the problems, the project runs but the GUI is not looking the same as it was in Netbeans 7.1.2!

If someone has any solutions, or experience the same issues please guide me to a possible solution!

Thanks! :)

Comment: Open the Project in the newer Version of Netbeans and it should work

Comment: Thank you for the response, I have try this solution already and no result. :)